# How to manipulate a toggle switch with DOM html

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, frontend, pug

I have designed a toggle button using Pug, and I am running function1 whenever it is clicked. But what I want to do is that when the page is loaded I am getting a value from the backend that I want to use to set the initial state of the toggle button. Is there a way to use DOM manipulation to change the toggle button below? or some other way to do it from client-side Javascript?

```
p Hours Button
  label.switch#toggleButton
  input(type='checkbox' onchange='function1(this)')
  span.slider.round
```

I am thinking maybe something like `document.getElementById("toggleButton").attr(checked)` or something like that. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a value of `true` or `false` in the property `state`, eg `{ state: true }` if using Express.

```
p Hours Button
  label.switch#toggleButton
  input(type="checkbox" onchange="function1(this)" checked=state)
  span.slider.round
```